# AngularJS TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I get this error in AngularJS:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Object.$get.e.$emit (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:87:296)
    at j (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:146:351)
    at http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:88:100
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at m (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:6:193)
    at Object.$get.e.$broadcast (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:88:63)
    at http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:80:114
    at k.promise.then.i (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:76:119)
    at k.promise.then.i (http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:76:119)
    at http://localhost/TestPortal/js/lib/angular.min.js:76:352
```

When calling this line of code in my controller:

```
function ClientController($scope, $routeParams, $location, StaticData, Client, IndustryFactory) {
     $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', someMethod);
}
```

Tried below which also doesn't help, same error:

```
ClientController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'StaticData', 'Client', 'IndustryFactory'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. See revised code:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { someMethod() });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `$scope` explicitly in your controller like this to make it work.

```
function ClientController($scope, $routeParams, $location, StaticData, Client, IndustryFactory) {
     $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', someMethod);
}


ClientController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location'];
```

Comment: Tried this: ClientController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'StaticData', 'Client', 'IndustryFactory']; Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This i believe is issue with minification of your code. Either inject the dependencies as described by @jayaram or use the the `[]` notation for dependencies and using modules. See the section `Notes on Minification` [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)